# Getting updated realtime output using subprocess

Tags: python

I have a python code that executes an `scp` command and attempts to process the output.

```
def execute(command):
    with subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line, end='') # process line here

    return p.returncode
```

However, `scp` has the progress indicator and this code completely misses it. The python code prints nothing and just waits for the `scp` to finish.

Is there any way to get this progress from `subprocess`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose python has subprocess run synchronously, so all output is flushed at once. [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) should be useful.